# Triggering click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, triggers, click

Hi I am working on a button which should trigger another, and it does not seem to be working. (Code for the trigger is at the bottom)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="google-tts.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!window.GoogleTTS) {
       $("#error").text("Sorry, the google-tts script couldn't be loaded.");
       return;
    } else {
       var HTML = '\
        <div> \
            <label for="demo_language">Language:</label> \
            <select id="demo_language"> \
                <option value="" disabled="disabled">(Select language)</option> \
            </select> \
        </div> \
        <div> \
            <label for="demo_text">Text:</label> \
            <input type="text" size="30" id="demo_text" value=""> \
        </div> \
        <button id="demo_play">Play!</button> \
        <div id="testbutton">\
        <form id="target" method = "post">\
        <button id="go">Go!</button>\
        </form>\
        </div>\
        ';
      $("#tts_demo").html(HTML);
    }

    var googleTts = new window.GoogleTTS();

    // setup language options
    $.each(googleTts.languages(), function(key, value) {
        $('#demo_language').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
    });

    // play
    $("#demo_play").click(function() {
        googleTts.play($("#demo_text").val(), $("#demo_language").val(), function(err) {
            if (err) {
                alert(err.toString());
            }
        });
    });

    // defaults
    $("#demo_language").val('zh-CN');
    $("#demo_text").val('中文');



                $("#go").click(function () {
                    $("#demo_play").trigger('click')
                    alert('one')
                })
});
</script>
```

Interestingly, the triggering seems to skip, and it goes straight to the alert.  I cannot seem to figure out how to make it work. Help please?

Comment: I've found that removing the <form> </form> around <button id="go">Go!</button> makes it work!  Not sure how I can do it without removing that though.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a few semicolons in that block of code:

```
            $("#go").click(function () {
                $("#demo_play").trigger('click')
                alert('one')
            })
```

Try this:

```
            $("#go").click(function () {
                $("#demo_play").trigger('click');
                alert('one');
            });
```

Comment: While it is a very good practice to use semicolons and to not rely on JavaScript's quirky semicolon insertion, it seems like the semicolons would be inserted correctly in this case. The problem is probably something else...

Comment: Thanks Greg, but I dont think that's the issue.  Its still not working.

Comment: @sabithpocker thanks for the tip, but it doesn't point out whats wrong here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/Qgvea/ Check this fiddle, its triggering the click fine.